# SPARK Is sample method on Dataframes uniform sampling?

Tags: apache-spark, sample, apache-spark-sql

I want to choose randomly a select number of rows from a dataframe and I know sample method does this, but I am concerned that my randomness should be uniform sampling? So, I was wondering if the sample method of Spark on Dataframes is uniform or not?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are a few code paths here:

- If `withReplacement = false && fraction > .4` then it uses a souped up random number generator (`rng.nextDouble() <= fraction`) and lets that do the work. **This seems like it would be pretty uniform.**
- If `withReplacement = false && fraction <= .4` then it uses a more complex algorithm ([`GapSamplingIterator`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/3c0156899dc1ec1f7dfe6d7c8af47fa6dc7d00bf/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/util/random/RandomSampler.scala#L217)) that also seems pretty uniform. At a glance, **it looks like it should be uniform also**
- If `withReplacement = true` it does close to the same thing, [except it can duplicate by the looks of it](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/3c0156899dc1ec1f7dfe6d7c8af47fa6dc7d00bf/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/util/random/RandomSampler.scala#L199), **so this looks to me like it would not be as uniform as the first two**

Comment: @Zara No problem. If it helped please do not forget to upvote and accept :)

Answer (score 0):

yes it is uniform, for more information you can try below code.
I hope this clarifies.

I think this should do the trick, where "data" is your data frame .
val splits = data.randomSplit(Array(0.7, 0.3))
val (trainingData, testData) = (splits(0), splits(1))