# How do simple random sampling and dataframe SAMPLE function work in Apache Spark (Scala)?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

Q1. I am trying to get a simple random sample out of a Spark dataframe (13 rows) using the sample function with parameters withReplacement: false, fraction: 0.6 but it gives me samples of different sizes every time I run it, though it work fine when I set the third parameter (seed). Why so?

Q2. How is the sample obtained after random number generation?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How is the sample obtained after random number generation?

Depending on a fraction you want to sample there are two different algorithms. You can check [Justin's Pihony](https://stackoverflow.com/users/779513/justin-pihony) answer to [SPARK Is sample method on Dataframes uniform sampling?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31633117/1560062)

> it gives me samples of different sizes every time I run it, though it work fine when I set the third parameter (seed). Why so?

If fraction is above `RandomSampler.defaultMaxGapSamplingFraction` sampling is done by [a simple filter](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/e9c36938ba972b6fe3c9f6228508e3c9f1c876b2/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/util/random/RandomSampler.scala#L166):

```
items.filter { _ => rng.nextDouble() <= fraction }
```

otherwise, simplifying things a little bit, it is repeatedly calling `drop` method using random integers and takes next item.

Keeping that in mind it should be obvious that a number of returned elements will be random with mean, assuming there is nothing wrong with `GapSamplingIterator`, equal  to fraction * rdd.count. If you set seed you get the same sequence of random numbers and as a consequence the same elements are included in the sample.

Answer (score 0):

The RDD API includes `takeSample`, which will return a "sample of specified size in an array".  It works by calling `sample` until it gets a sample size greater than the requested one, then randomly taking the specified number from that.  The code comments that it shouldn't have to iterate often due to a bias toward large sample sizes.