# Spark: increase the size of an RDD using sample with replacement

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a RDD[(String,Array[String])] and I need to replicate the data inside to increase the size of it.

I've read here https://stackoverflow.com/a/41787801/9759150 with replacemente you can get the same element in sample twice.

For example:

If RDD.count() is, let's say, 35 elements, and I need to generate from it an RDD with 200 elements. How can I do this?

I saw applying sample is like this:

```
val sampledRDD = rdd.sample(true, fraction, seed)
```

I do not how can I choose `fraction` parameter to my problem.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was doing some tests and I figured out that .sample() is able to do the thing that I wanted!. The key is keep with replacement in `true` (as I said in the question), `seed` could be whatever (a number, of course), but `fraction` should be:

```
val fraction = num_new.toDouble / rdd.count()  // following my examle: num_new is 200, and rdd.count() is 35

val sampledRDD = rdd.sample(true, fraction, seed)
```

In this case, `fraction = 5.71428571428571`, that means the `sampledRDD` will have each element of it `fraction` repeated times.

Comment: huh, that is easier. And interesting.

Answer (score 1):

You can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32837530/how-to-get-a-sample-with-an-exact-sample-size-in-spark-rdd) answer for more information about the meaning of fraction in rdd.sample(). The short story is, it represents the probability of drawing a sample.  This means the final rdd won't be guaranteed to be *exactly* equal to the specified fraction*original size.

I would approach this in the opposite direction:

1. First, generate an RDD that is simply the original RDD, repeated several times
2. Now, sample out of that RDD down to the size you want.

Something like:

```
val rdds = (1 to 10).map(_ => originalRdd)
val bigRdd = sc.union(rdds)
val sampledRdd = bigRdd.sample(true, fraction, seed)
```

and set fraction such that the final RDD is the size you want:

```
val fraction = numResultsIWant/100*originalRdd.count()
```

and we picked `10` there because that was the number of copies of the RDD we created.

Comment: It would be great to apply this approach. But in the first line, I got this message: `cannot resolve symbol map`.

Comment: Sorry. I've edited the answer. Let me know if that works for you.