# How is `sample` different from `TABLESAMPLE` in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'd like to get create a random sub-sample of my data.

1. Spark's `sample` function ([link](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.1/api/scala/org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaHadoopRDD.html#sample(withReplacement:Boolean,fraction:Double):org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD%5BK,V%5D)) is the API I'd like to use. Particularly, because it allows me to toggle if the sampling is done with or without replacement. However, executing this function takes a long time. Based on the answers from this question [Spark sample is too slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50004006/spark-sample-is-too-slow), it seems like `sample` requires a full table scan.
2. TABLESAMPLE seems like a faster alternative, albeit, the ability to toggle with and without replacement is lost.

I'd like to understand how `sample` and TABLESAMPLE are different, and why does TABLESAMPLE execute faster than `sample`. Could it be that TABLESAMPLE does not require a full table scan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TABLESAMPLE` has three ways of sampling:

- **percentage (or fraction)**: under the hood, does the same thing as sample. It is used to create uniform sampling.
- **num_rows**: under the hood, does the same thing as LIMIT, which is why this API is very fast.
- **bucket OUT OF**: specifies the portion out of the total to sample.

This is stated on the documentation:

> Always use TABLESAMPLE (percent PERCENT) if randomness is important. TABLESAMPLE (num_rows ROWS) is not a simple random sample but instead is implemented using LIMIT.

So the answer whether `sample` and `TABLESAMPLE` are the same thing is no, but `TABLESAMPLE` used with percentage (fraction) and `sample` are the same thing.

If you want to read more about this, Databricks has some good information about [this](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-qry-select-sampling.html).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I acknowledge that `sample` is different from `TABLESAMPLE` but my question is trying to understand what exactly is the difference, especially as it relates to query plans/stuff under the hood. I observe that TABLESAMPLE is much faster and I have no clue why.

Comment: `TABLESAMPLE` with fraction is not faster than `sample`, but `TABLESAMPLE` with a positive integer as argument is, but the sampling is created by taking first X rows of the dataset, meaning that no full table scan is necessary, as there is no need to create a uniform sampling. 

From the documentation:
`LIMIT`: Returns a new Dataset by taking the first n rows. -> taking first N rows requires no table scan, but the sampling is not proper (we can take first 100 rows without checking the whole dataset).
`SAMPLE`: Returns a new Dataset by sampling a fraction of rows

Comment: @vilabinot thanks, i think your answer sufficiently addresses my question, if you'd like to submit that as an "Answer" I would be happy to mark it as the solution.