# Dataframe sample in Apache spark | Scala

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, sample

I'm trying to take out samples from two dataframes wherein I need the ratio of count maintained. eg

```
df1.count() = 10
df2.count() = 1000

noOfSamples = 10
```

I want to sample the data in such a way that i get 10 samples of size 101 each( 1 from df1 and 100 from df2)

Now while doing so,

```
var newSample = df1.sample(true, df1.count() / noOfSamples)
println(newSample.count())
```

What does the fraction here imply? can it be greater than 1? I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31633117/spark-is-sample-method-on-dataframes-uniform-sampling) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32229941/how-do-simple-random-sampling-and-dataframe-sample-function-work-in-apache-spark) but wasn't able to comprehend it fully.

Also is there anyway we can specify the number of rows to be sampled?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The `fraction` parameter represents the **aproximate** fraction of the dataset that will be returned. For instance, if you set it to `0.1`, 10% (1/10) of the rows will be returned. For your case, I believe you want to do the following:

```
val newSample = df1.sample(true, 1D*noOfSamples/df1.count)
```

However, you may notice that `newSample.count` will return a different number each time you run it, and that's because the `fraction` will be a threshold for a random-generated value (as you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32229941/)), so the resulting dataset size can vary. An workaround can be:

```
val newSample = df1.sample(true, 2D*noOfSamples/df1.count).limit(df1.count/noOfSamples)
```

**Some scalability observations**

You may note that doing a `df1.count` might be expensive as it evaluates the whole *DataFrame*, and you'll lose one of the benefits of sampling in the first place.

Therefore depending on the context of your application, you may want to use an already **known** number of total samples, or an approximation.

```
val newSample = df1.sample(true, 1D*noOfSamples/knownNoOfSamples)
```

Or assuming the size of your *DataFrame* as huge, I would still use a `fraction` and use `limit` to force the number of samples.

```
val guessedFraction = 0.1
val newSample = df1.sample(true, guessedFraction).limit(noOfSamples)
```

**As for your questions:**

> can it be greater than 1?

No. It represents a fraction between 0 and 1. If you set it to 1 it will bring 100% of the rows, so it wouldn't make sense to set it to a number larger than 1.

> Also is there anyway we can specify the number of rows to be sampled?

You can specify a larger fraction than the number of rows you want and then use limit, as I show in the second example. Maybe there is another way, but this is the approach I use.

Comment: Although its more clear to me what the fraction does but the solution you have suggested might not work in the current scenario (See Edits). df2.sample(true, noOfSample / df2.count).limit(df2.count/noOfSamples) would give me 1% of the data i.e 10 rows which would be less than 100 rows i require. Any thoughts on this ?

Comment: @hbabbar So you always want 10% of each dataset? If so, you could do `df2.sample(true, 0.15).limit(0.1*df2.count)`

Comment: Great solution!

Comment: I'm running Spark 3.0.2 and the fraction can be greater than 1 (assuming sampling with replacement), not sure if/when that changed.  This is also made clear in an answer below.

Answer (score 5):

To answer your question, is there anyway we can specify the number of rows to be sampled?

I recently needed to sample a certain number of rows from a spark data frame. I followed the below process,

1. Convert the spark data frame to rdd.
   Example: `df_test.rdd`
2. RDD has a functionality called takeSample which allows you to give the number of samples you need with a seed number.
   Example: `df_test.rdd.takeSample(withReplacement, Number of Samples, Seed)`
3. Convert RDD back to spark data frame using `sqlContext.createDataFrame()`

Above process combined to single step:

Data Frame (or Population) I needed to Sample from has around 8,000 records:
df_grp_1

```
df_grp_1
test1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(df_grp_1.rdd.takeSample(False,125,seed=115))
```

test1 data frame will have 125 sampled records.

Answer (score 3):

To answer if the fraction can be greater than 1. Yes, it can be if we have replace as yes. If a value greater than 1 is provided with replace false, then following exception will occur:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Upper bound (2.0) must be <= 1.0.
```

Answer (score 2):

I too find lack of sample by count functionality disturbing. If you are not picky about creating a temp view I find the code below useful (df is your dataframe, count is sample size):

```
val tableName = s"table_to_sample_${System.currentTimeMillis}"
df.createOrReplaceTempView(tableName)
val sampled = sqlContext.sql(s"select *, rand() as random from ${tableName} order by random limit ${count}")
sqlContext.dropTempTable(tableName)
sampled.drop("random")
```

It returns an exact count as long as your current row count is as large as your sample size.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you can do exactly the same query with the DataFrame API, there's no need to create the temp view and use an SQL query. However, this would trigger a sort operation and I believe it would be considerably slower than using sample.

Answer (score 2):

The below code works if you want to do a random split of 70% & 30% of a data frame df,

```
val Array(trainingDF, testDF) = df.randomSplit(Array(0.7, 0.3), seed = 12345)
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this function for random sampling when exact number of records are desirable:

```
def row_count_sample (df, row_count, with_replacement=False, random_seed=113170):

    ratio = 1.08 * float(row_count) / df.count()  # random-sample more as dataframe.sample() is not a guaranteed to give exact record count
                                                  # it could be more or less actual number of records returned by df.sample()

    if ratio>1.0:
        ratio = 1.0

    result_df = (df
                    .sample(with_replacement, ratio, random_seed)
                    .limit(row_count)                                   # since we oversampled, make exact row count here
                )

    return result_df
```

Answer (score -3):

May be you want to try below code..

```
val splits = data.randomSplit(Array(0.7, 0.3))
val (trainingData, testData) = (splits(0), splits(1))
```