# Why are the results inconsistent for sampling in R vs sampling in spark

Tags: r, apache-spark, random, dataframe, seed

I have a dataframe that I needed to get samples from and perform operations on in spark but even after setting a seed value, I'm not getting the exact same samples in each run. ([How can I make my dataframe sample in each run using apache spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42387381/how-can-i-make-my-dataframe-sample-in-each-run-using-apache-spark?noredirect=1#comment72115946_42387381)) 
whereas I get the exact same samples on the same dataframe every time when i do a sampling in R with a seed value.

Is this expected behavior and also is this acceptable?