# Calculating Kernel Density of every column in a Spark DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

is there a way to calculate KDE of every column of a DataFrame?

I have a DataFrame where each column represents the values of one feature. The KDE function of Spark MLLib needs an `RDD[Double]` of the sample values. The problem is I need to find a way without collecting the values for each column, because that would slow down the program to much.

Does anyone have an idea how I could solve that? Sadly all my tries failed till now.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can create a new RDD using sample function ([refer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37416825/dataframe-sample-in-apache-spark-scala)) and then perform your operation to get the optimal performance.