# Filtering parquet file on read with PySpark

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, amazon-emr

I have a huge dataset of partitioned parquet files stored in AWS s3 and I want to read only a sample from each month of data using AWS EMR. I have to filter data for each month by a value "user_id" selecting, for example, data from 100.000 users (out of millions) and writing the aggregations back to s3.

I figured out how to read and write to s3 using EMR clusters, but I tested on a very small dataset. For the real dataset, I need to filter data to be able to process it. How to do this using pyspark?

Comment: Those 100.000 users you want to filter with are stored in a collection, in a dataframe or you just want some random users?

Comment: I actually have them stored not as users, but events performed by users. I already have a written script to transform this event-level file to a user-level table, but now I am facing the issue of reading from a partitioned parquet file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spark has multiple sampling transformations. `df.sample(...)` is the one you want in your case. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37416825/dataframe-sample-in-apache-spark-scala).

If you need an exact number of results back, you have to (a) over-sample by a little and then (b) use `df.limit()` to get the exact number.

If you can deal with just a fraction, as opposed to a target count, you can save `df.count`.

Comment: Thanks, this answer is enough for what I asked, though my problem evolved to a more specific version of what I asked. Thanks anyway :)