# Pyspark: Doing a count on sample of dataframe instead whole dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I currently have some code that computes the overall time taken to run the count operation on a dataframe. I have another implementation which measures the time taken to run count on a sampled version of this dataframe.

```
sampled_df = df.sample(withReplacement=False, fraction=0.1)
sampled_df.count()
```

I then extrapolate the overall count from the sampled count. But I do not see an overall decrease in the time taken for calculating this sampled count when compared to doing a count on the whole dataset. Both seem to take around 40 seconds. Is there a reason this happens? Also, is there an improvement in terms of memory when using a sampled count over count on whole dataframe?

Comment: Can you please provide us with both data frames?

Comment: Please show the SQL DAG so that you can understand why it takes similar time

Comment: How big is your data? 40s to run the whole program doesn't seem like a lot. The actual count may be only taking a couple of seconds, and perhaps you are not seeing much of a difference overall.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [countApprox](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.RDD.countApprox.html).  This lets you choose how long your willing to wait for an approximate count/confidence interval.

Sample still needs to access all partitions to create a [sample that is uniform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31633117/spark-is-sample-method-on-dataframes-uniform-sampling).  You aren't really saving anytime using a sample.

Comment: Are there any memory benefits to doing a count on a sample instead of the whole dataframe? Even if time does not reduce, if it saves some memory, that would be of great help!

Comment: the most expensive operation is visiting every partition, which is why you aren't seeing any performance boost right now.